# ASUS P8Z77-V PRO/TB & Apple Thunderbolt Displays

Tags: multiple-monitors, thunderbolt

I just setup a new PC with the new ASUS P8Z77-V PRO/THUNDERBOLT and am currently able to get one of my two thunderbolt displays working.  The second one is outputting sound, but no video...

Any ideas?

Comment: If [this question's accepted answer is correct](http://superuser.com/questions/441395/what-is-the-maximum-resolution-that-a-thunderbolt-monitor-can-display), you should be able to use two displays with up to 1920x1200 pixels, or one with 2560x1440/1600

Answer (score 0):

Are you daisy chaining your displays from that single Thunderbolt port? I don't think that will work.

Only Macs with dedicated graphics are known to be able to drive two thunderbolt displays on one cable. The on-board Intel graphics may not even be able to output that many pixels. (The spec says `- Supports Thunderbolt with max. resolution 2560 x 1600 @ 60 Hz`)There's also the protocol problem of sending two streams on one cable.

You'd better connect your second monitor via another port.

Comment: [Asus website](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8Z77V_PROTHUNDERBOLT/#specifications): *Data transfer rate up to 10 Gbps;   Daisy-chain up to 6 Thunderbolt devices*

Comment: But the monitor is based on the display port protocol, not the PCI-E protocol.... Some Thunderbolt-enabled Macs don't even allow you to daisy chain monitors.

Comment: @billc.cn which is the confusing piece...  I'm contacting their "support" today to see if they can provide any final answers.

Comment: Diasy chaining (with DP1.2 MST on all devices) should just work... but you share your bandwidth.